# Is this too DRY, am I going overboard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, dry

I've been drying some code, one of this refactors is as following:
I have 3 controllers ( ConstructionCompanies, RealEstateCompanies, People) all of which had the following pattern:

```
class ConstructionCompaniesController < ApplicationController
before_filter :correct_user, :only => [:edit, :update]

private
   def correct_user
      @company = ConstructionCompany.find(params[:id]) 
      if(current_user.owner != @company.user)
        redirect_to(root_path)
      end
    end
```

```
class RealEstateCompaniesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :correct_user, :only => [:edit, :update]
...

private
   def correct_user
      @company = RealEstateCompany.find(params[:id]) 
      if(current_user.owner != @company.user)
        redirect_to(root_path)
      end
    end
```

As you can see the correct_user is repeated in each controller.
So what I did inside I helper that is included for all of them I created a method:

```
def correct_user_for_seller_of_controller(controller)
    #"User".classify will return the class User etc.
    @seller = controller.controller_name.classify.constantize.find(params[:id])     
    redirect_to(root_path) unless (current_user == @seller.user)
  end
```

Know inside each controller I have:

```
class ConstructionCompaniesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :only => [:edit, :update] do |controller| correct_user_for_seller_of_controller(controller) end
```

```
class RealEstateCompaniesController < ApplicationController

 before_filter :only => [:edit, :update] do |controller| correct_user_for_seller_of_controller(controller) end
```

I like the fact that is DRY now, but the problem is that it seems a little to complex for me, hard to understand. Did I went too far ?

Comment: @KandadaBoggu: I didn't even see that. Wow, nice catch xD

Comment: It was a big A**, difficult to miss ... :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `correct_user` method to the `ApplicationController` class.

```
class ApplicationController
  def correct_user_for_seller_of_controller
    #"User".classify will return the class User etc.
    @seller = controller_name.classify.constantize.find(params[:id])     
    redirect_to(root_path) unless (current_user == @seller.user)
  end  
end
```

In your controllers use the new method as a filter method:

```
class RealEstateCompaniesController < ApplicationController

 before_filter :correct_user_for_seller_of_controller, :only => [:edit, :update]

end
```

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely good to clean that up. I think you may have made things slightly more complex than necessary, though, what with all the Proc whatnot.

If the filter is being run on an instance of the controller, then there's no need to pass the controller to itself. Just call `controller_name` within the method and you're good to go.

Comment: yes, self.controller_name so I could get rid of the argument, but I still have to do self.controller_name.classify.constantize

Comment: @daniel: The blocks are the really messy bit. That little method chain is absolutely fine, especially since it's only used once.

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally DRY it a bit more and move the filter to a superclass (or AppplicationController).

The method itself could also definitely be simplified. Use some introspection for example.

Comment: yep good ideas, I'll right some more code up, use some introspection and move the verify for edit and update of all my Controllers to the ApplicationController, it should be like 6 or 7 lines

Comment: @daniel: only move the `before_filter` bit to the application controller if you're definitely not planning on making any more controllers in the near future. Just a reminder :)

Comment: @Matchu exactly what I meant ;)